# Selecting and updating all the specific integer values from a string

Tags: java, string

If I am given a integer value like 100, then I have to update all the occurrences of the text "Writing No 1" to "Writing No 101"

Actual text:

> Collection reference 4 -> My Main Text 4 -> It's writing 3 Writing No 1
>
> Writing No 2   Writing NO 3
>
> I have given three previous references.

As I am given the 100, so I output would like this.

> Collection reference 4 -> My Main Text 104 -> It's writing 3 Writing No 101
>
> Writing No 102 Writing NO 103
>
> I have given three previous references.

How to update **Writing No 1** to **Writing NO 101** and other in the same way using Java?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean and want. What do you mean by *reference*? Could you clearly separate what is in the parent doc, and what is in the child one?

Comment: I want to update all Writing (No int-value) with increment by base value. e.g. if i have two text like Writing No 1 and Writing No 2 and based value is  200, then result should be like this. Writing No 201 and Writing No 202. All other text should not be affected.

Comment: What is based value ? Your question is very unclear

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question, you got to replace the string based on the integer values.
Better you write a function for the same like this-

```
    String text = new String("Writing No 1");
    public void demo(int num) {
     text .replace(text.slice(-1), num);
    }
```

Where you can pass any integer value and can even use loop for the multiple string values.
Hope i was helpful.

Comment: Yes, I have to, Like in a text file, I would have old Values, like Writing No 1, So I need to find that and update it to updated value 101. remember there could be hundreds of Such values in a single text file. Like Writing No 1, Writing No 50, Writing No 23 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% this is what you need, but I'll give it a try:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inc = 100;
        String text = "Collection reference 4 -> My Main Text 4 -> It's writing 3 Writing No 1 \nWriting No 2 Writing NO 3 \nI have given three previous references.";
        String patten = "(\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+) (\\d) (\\D+)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patten, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2) + " " + matcher.group(3) + " "
                + inc(matcher.group(4), inc) + " " + matcher.group(5) + " " + matcher.group(6) + " " + matcher.group(7)
                + " " + inc(matcher.group(8), inc) + " " + matcher.group(9) + " " + inc(matcher.group(10), inc) + " "
                + matcher.group(11) + " " + inc(matcher.group(12), inc) + matcher.group(13));
    }

    private static int inc(String base, int inc) {
        return Integer.valueOf(base) + inc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me look into this

Comment: tried but not useful. My problems is not solved. Thanks anyways